# Remove Server 2012 Remote Access Server

Tags: vpn, powershell, windows-server-2012, remote-access, uninstall

My IT director was walking me through setting up a Server 2012 VPN/RA server. We did not do this in our test environment, and now I would like to remove it.

I know that when installing this server it makes domain changes such as creating group policies etc, and I want to make sure when I remove it I do it properly.

The only documentation I can find from Microsoft, is regarding the Uninstall-RemoteAccess powershell command.

Will running this correctly remove the role, and undo any changes made to the domain and group policies?

Comment: And your IT director did this in production?!?

Comment: He is director of the group IT, and is based in another office of our parent company. He was visiting for a day and wanted to run through it. We did not have enough time to set up a test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say that I know for certain, but after reading [the documentation on the Uninstall-RemoteAccess cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918390.aspx) I feel pretty certain saying that it doesn't remove every change made to the system. It says, among other things, the following, which I feel is the answer to your question:

> The Unistall-RemoteAccess cmdlet uninstalls DirectAccess (DA) and VPN, both Remote Access (RA) VPN >and site-to-site VPN.
>
> [...]
>
> This cmdlet will not handle removal of RA role and other dependent roles.

Since it explicitly states that it doesn't even remove the RA role, I feel pretty certain to say that it doesn't undo all changes. I can't comment on the specifics of group policy changes, but as a *pure guess* I would say that it doesn't undo such things.